# Adding a WHERE clause to a JOIN statement

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, employees and holidays.

I am trying to select a list of employees, their allowed holiday and their remaining holiday left after looking at holidays entered for **this year**.

The tables look like this (important rows shown only)

```
employees
    id,
    name,
    allowed_holiday

holiday
    id,
    employee,
    num_days,
    date_to
```

I have the current query that finds these values fine, but I want to add a WHERE clause to only count holiday against the employee if date_to > xxxx-09-01 AND < xxxx-09-01.

```
    SELECT 
        e.id,
        e.name,
        e.allowed_holiday,
        (e.allowed_holiday - SUM(h.num_days)) AS remaining
    FROM
        employees AS e
    LEFT JOIN 
        holiday AS h
    ON
        h.employee = e.id
    GROUP BY
        e.name
    ORDER BY 
        e.name ASC
```

I'm not sure where to add the WHERE clause for this though without it removing employees from the data with no holiday listed.

Answer (score 6):

As you are doing a LEFT join, the filter conditions must be on the ON statement. So in your case it'd look like this:

```
SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.name,
    e.allowed_holiday,
    (e.allowed_holiday - SUM(h.num_days)) AS remaining
FROM
    employees AS e
LEFT JOIN 
    holiday AS h
ON
    h.employee = e.id AND h.to_date between xxxx-09-01 and xxxx-09-01
GROUP BY
    e.name
ORDER BY 
    e.name ASC
```

Comment: While it's possible to add conditions to INNER join as WHERE clauses, I personally prefer to add them on the ON statement just to match te LEFT and RIGHT join statements. But stil, filters to the man table have to be at WHERE statement, so it looks kind of weird. That's why I like ORACLE's approach better.

Answer (score 2):

Add the condition on `h.date_to` into the `ON` clause not the `WHERE` to avoid turning it back into an `INNER JOIN`

```
  LEFT JOIN 
        holiday AS h
    ON
        h.employee = e.id AND h.date_to > ....
```